# Prove that $V= \text{Im} f \oplus \ker{g}$

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $f:U \rightarrow V$ and $g: V \rightarrow W$ be two linear maps between vector spaces above $\mathbb{R},$ such that $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism. Prove that $$V= \text{Im} f \oplus \ker{g}.$$

My attempt: Using the fact that $g\circ f$ is an isomorphism, we have $f$ is injective and $g$ is surjective. So, let $v \in V$ such that $v \in \text{Im} f$ and $v \in \ker{g},$ then $v=f(u)$ for some $u \in U$. Then $g(f(u))=g(v)=0, $ so $u=0$ which implies that $v=0.$ Thus $\text{Im} f \cap \ker{g}={0}.$

Now, let us see that $V=\text{Im} f + \ker{g}.$ Here is my doubt I don't know how to write $v$ as sum of $x+y$ where $x \in \text{Im} f$ and $y \in \ker{g}.$

Comment: $\mathrm{img}~f ⊂ W$, so you should use an isomorphism sign in $V \cong \mathrm{img}~f \oplus \ker g$. Otherwise it gets confusing as there is such a thing as an internal direct sum which should be contrasted to the external direct sum.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\im}{\mathrm{im}}$

Let $v \in V$ be given. Then $g(v) \in W$. But $g \circ f:U \to W$ is an isomorphism. So $g(v) = g(f(u))$ with $u \in U$. So $g(v - f(u)) = 0$. So $v - f(u) \in \ker g$ and $v = f(u) + (v - f(u)) \in \im f + \ker g$.

Comment: That is right thank you